# @firebase/auth: Auth (9.6.1): INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Expected a class definition

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, jestjs

When I run yarn test it just fails

```
import AdminLogin from './adminLogin'

it('it works', () => {
    const comp = renderer.create(<AdminLogin />).toJSON();
    expect(comp).toMatchSnapshot();
})
```

Comment: Hi, I encountered the same problem. Did you resolve it?